# Color objects based on distance in Animation Nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation-nodes

How do I set colors of objects based on their distances from some reference object, an empty for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the *Set Vertex Color Node* to color the objects, I will compute the distance between an empty and some objects, then loop over the objects, create a color based on the distance and set it:

[image: Node Tree]

The previous tree uses the distance as the hue, which produces:

[image: Result]

But we can use it as the value for instance:

[image: Result 2]

To use the vertex color as the color in a material, we check *Vertex Color Paint* in the material options:

[image: Material]

Lastly, if you are using the *Object Instancer Node* to make the objects, make sure to check *Deep Copy* making each of the meshes independent. And of course, give the source object the required material.

Comment: Omar, can I look at your bend file? I'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: And also how to do it for Cycles?

Comment: YES!!!! I Did it) http://prntscr.com/iytobu
http://prntscr.com/iytpbs
Thanks for your help Omar!
But the gradient is looped! 
Is it possible to make so that next to the object there was a certain gradient. And no matter how far the controller is from the grid, the color was always different?

Comment: @SergeyGolubev You can multiply the distance by some scalar to control how much times it is looped. If you want it to stop at the last color, use the *Clamp Number Node* to make it between 0-1.