# How to change color only of selected objects in a matrix?

Tags: animation-nodes, vertex-colors, matrix

I'm trying to exempt a couple of objects from being colored by an 'empty' which is coloring the cube matrix based on the distance.

In the image there are 2 empties: one is coloring the cubes blue, the orther coloring them red and offseting by X.
[image]

What could I do if I wanted those 3 selected cubes, not to be colored by the 'empty' object?
For coloring method I used roughly similar method as in here:
[Color objects based on distance in Animation Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105315/color-objects-based-on-distance-in-animation-nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *List Boolean Operations* node to removed the selected objects from your object list as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Hey, Omar, Thank you for suggestion. I understood what boolean does. But I think I lack something more. Maybe I did not explained my problem to the foolest. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/194901346183413761/515248801896726537/unknown.png In my case I need to work with object group and I'm kind of confused how to linke whats was cut out from the main group.

Comment: @JuliusRa Use the output of the boolean node as your loop input. That way, the required objects will be excluded from the coloring.

Comment: I tried it.. The excluded cubes loose their position.. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/194901346183413761/515246653704503346/unknown.png Thats is why I think thought way is not an option and tried to look for a way to detour the loop somehow.. But I guess it is not that simple

Comment: @JuliusRa Make two separate loops, one for colors with the new list and one for transformation with the original list. Makes sense?

Comment: Well.. hmm it works.. Kinda.. :)  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/195644373336195072/515286470664257556/unknown.png But somehow it glitches from time to time.. especially if I copy loop node, not create it from scratch.. need to ponder more around this.. Anyway thanks.. I'll keep this question open.. and check If I find a more optimised solution.. I still want to find some way to influence the cubes maybe through shaders/vertex colors.. so that I could make changes inside the same loop.

Comment: @JuliusRa One thing you should do is put the falloff node outside of the loop and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm.. Should  I add it as a new parameter? I guess it should reduce the amount of iteration that are calculated for the loop.. Do I understand you thought correctly?

Comment: @JuliusRa Yes, it should be passed as a parameter. The falloff is constant in all iterations, so recreating it at each iteration is inefficient. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Sure.. Thing.. I kind of was unable to find a propper solution my self, and project pushed me to go for a work around. But I still got a lot of great ideas for future. So thank you!